# Why would I want to update the iOS on my iPad 2?

Tags: software-update, ipad

I have an iPad 2 which I have neglected to update for some time now.  The iPad uses iOS version 6 currently.  iOS 6 has never given me issues the way i use my iPad so Should I update to the new version?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that has gotten me finally persuaded to update to iOS 8 was the fact that more and more apps called for mandatory update and would otherwise refuse to run. The one that immediately comes to mind in NFL Game Pass. Also my kids told me that some of the games they wanted to play wouldn't run on iOS 6.

I must say that I was a little afraid to upgrade as I was expecting performance issues on part of iPad 2... I am pleasantly suprised though - there are of course minor lags here and there, but it's not like the update has rendered the iPad unusable - on the contrary.

So all in all if it's just a matter of preference - it's entirely up to you whether you do it or not, but if you have essential apps calling for the upgrade, I don't see a reason to stay with iOS 6.

I hope that has shed some light on the matter for you.

Answer (score 1):

No, I certainly recommend that you do not upgrade. It is unfortunate that you don't have iOS 7, but in any case, I upgraded my 3rd generation iPad to iOS 8 and noticed an immediate performance difference. The keystrokes were almost always delayed by roughly a word. They have fixed that problem as of some of the .0.1 versions, though. Still, I have observed a number of people upgrade and wish they hadn't. The fact is that after you upgrade, there is no going back.

If everything is working as it is right now, stay with it. If you need something that runs iOS 8, then go with that.

Also, keep in mind that iOS 8 has the potential to be the last option for the iPad 2. If this is the case (and you will know after WWDC, likely), then you will always have the option to upgrade, even after iOS 9 comes out.